# Высота блока меню при разных разрешениях

Tags: html, css

Есть блок меню, его высота 130%, при iPhone 6 его высоты с лихвой хватает, но при iPhone 4 его становится мало, как сделать чтобы высота автоматически подстраивалась, учитывая что оно пролистывается `height:auto` в этом случае не подходит

Iphone 6:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Iphone 4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS:

```
.swipemenu {
    width: 80%;
    background: #eeeeee;
    height: 130%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 4%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: -400px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
    transition: left 0.3s;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Зы. Задавать большую высоту, значит увеличивать блок на других разрешениях и скролл его будет больше, мне этого не надо.

Comment: Я бы выставил 100vh родителю, сверху перекрыл затеняющим градиентом цвета фона, указывая, что внизу что-то есть и можно скроллить и соответственно дать эту возможность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

Используем для высоты единицу измерения `vh` - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Если контент целиком не помещается и выходит за область сверху или снизу от блока - добавляем свойство `overflow-y: auto;`
Это свойство добавляет вертикальную полосу прокрутки при необходимости.

```css
.swipemenu {
  width: 80%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 4%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 4%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.swipemenu ul {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.swipemenu ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.swipemenu ul a:hover {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="swipemenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```